# Is there any way relevant to android's Range class in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to check that a value intersects() of the two values.

In android, I found the Range class which contains constructer `Range(T lower, T upper)`.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Range.html

In c#, How can I do like that?

thanks.

Comment: What has "I want to check that a value intersects() of the two values" got to do with `Range(T lower, T upper)`? You need to read [ask] and then fix your question.

Answer (score 1):

With Linq:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Range(
    int start,
    int count
)
```

You can read the example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)